# How is UT1 being computed?

Tags: astronomy, time, metrology

I've recently read up about [time standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_time#Versions) and now understand that UTC is a second-corrected version of international atomic time so that it is kept within 0.9s from UT1. And then UT1 is defined as the mean solar time at 0° longitude. However, it is not realized by measurements of the sun's apparent position, but via a sidereal time or earth rotation angle.

Extensive googling hasn't helped me to understand how this observed earth rotation angle is used to compute UT1. [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/46836/2451) Phys.SE answer hints that the equation is quite complex. I'd like to understand why it needs to be complex, considering that the "mean sun" that [mean solar time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_time#Mean_solar_time) refers to is defined to follow a uniform movement (with respect to the stars) along the celestial equator. Therefore, shouldn't the difference between sidereal time and mean solar time be simply a linear function of the time of year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in: [this lecture](http://iau-c31.nict.go.jp/pdf/2009_IAUGA_JD6/JD06_capitaine_wallace.pdf)

Earth's angle of rotation = 2π(0.7790572732640 + 1.00273781191135448(Julian UT1date - 2451545.0)) radians.

So one observes Earth's angle of rotation and calculates the Julian UT1 date as a decimal date from that formula.  Then, subtracting out the "day" portion of the date, you get a fraction of a day that you could convert to an hours, minutes, seconds time.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the answer. So it is a linear function as I suspected.

Comment: That may be the majority of formulas out there but take a quick look at this funtion of the SOFA C library http://www.iausofa.org/2012_0301_C/sofa/era00.c Just an FYI because something doesn't seem right here.

Comment: Take the first term and multiply it by 360 and you will get a familiar number which is an offset angle used in many of the GMST formulas. This is just a convenient way to keep it time based.